# Iframe full screen error

Tags: css, html, iframe

i have an Iframe that i use it for showing my landing pages demo, it has full width and hight of the screen by using % unit, but some of my landing pages has a header with 100% height so when i use them within the Iframe, it shows only the header of landing pages, is there any way to do it on jquery thanks

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
iframe {
    width:  -webkit-fill-available;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Try this

Comment: what is the meaning of fill-available

Comment: it fills the your total window height or width